# How to get number from String sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get number from String in sql
Example: mn21 or mnp100, how to get number from "mb21" or "mnp100". 
Then, i will sort order by numeric

Comment: Do all strings end in a number?

Comment: yes, but they have different lenght

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `PATINDEX` to search for the start index of the number and then `RIGHT` to get the remaining numbers:

```
WITH SampleData(string) AS(
    SELECT 'mn21' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'mnp100'
)
SELECT
    string, 
    Number = CAST(RIGHT(string, LEN(string) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', string) + 1) AS INT)
FROM SampleData
ORDER BY Number
```